# Delphi cxGrid How to prevent the creation of a second row of headers when moving columns?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

Delphi cxGrid.
How to prevent the creation of a second row of headers when moving columns?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a Table view instead of a Band view?

Comment: In `OnColumnPosChanged` handler set `TcxGridBandedColumn(AColumn).Position.RowIndex:=0;`.

Comment: @BrakNicku using the TcxGridBandedColumn cast on a regular cxGridDBColumn produces an AV for me, which is not surprising.  Obviously it will work with TcxGridBandedColumn descendants but should be superfluous with those.

Comment: @Martyna no, this event is derived from parent class so the cast is not superfluous and obviously using this code with normal table view makes no sense - it does not support stacked columns.

Comment: @BrakNick Thanks for solving the problem!